# space not firing onChange event

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In my ReactJS project, I have a simple controlled input. When I press the spacebar, the `onChange` event is not fired. Is this normal behavior? Change I change it?

```
    <input
      type="text"
      onChange={(e) => {
        console.log(e.target.value + 'here');
      }}
      value={this.state.name}
    />
```

Typing `"test         "` would result in a log output of `testhere` and the spacebar won't even fire the event.

**EDIT**

So I've just created a new project from scratch, and this is not the default behavior. So my question is how can I diagnose this? (This is not my code that I wrote).

Comment: React is suppressing space for you. Last white space is automatically removed. you can try hit space and write something.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a solution like this

[image: Have a look into this code, Thankyou]

Comment: yes, exactly. It works in a separate project, so this issue is localized to my one component and I don't know how to diagnose it.

Comment: Hi friend, to diagnose your application use The react developer tools, there is an extension for it on chrome or use the "Debugger fro chrome" in VS code https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PJeNReqyH88&t=301s

Comment: If you still cannot get the answer you are looking for, plz give us more information on your question I am happy to help

Answer (score 0):

You need to setState of your variable to work. Else for every change in event it will just log out each letter like this

[image]

Comment: I understand that. I have created a purposefully broken example to illustrate that the event is not firing. Even with the code the way it is above, any text typed into the input is displayed in the log. I.e., "test" is logged out to the console as "test", even though in the input it stays empty.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is: you're assigning the `state` variable as the `value` of your textinput but you're not updating your state value, so your text input value will never change doesn't matter if your type space or any other character.

```
<input
  type="text"
  onChange={(e) => {
    this.setState({name: e.target.value}) // you must update the value to stat
    console.log(e.target.value + 'here')
  }}
  value={this.state.name} // here you assing the value
/>
```

Comment: No, this is not the issue. OP is asking when the event isn't firing at all. The event should be firing regardless of setting state. I added the bounty here because I was experiencing a similar issue, but I resolved it - the issue for me, and most likely for OP too, was that an unrelated keyboard listener was intercepting the key press on spacebar.

Answer (score 0):

You can try use onkeydown event to detect the space input , then if space firing
keydown event, I guess its some Event conflict ,you can fix it in onKeydown like this.

```
 const handleKeyDown =(e:any) => {
    if(e.key===' '){
        e.stopPropagation()
    }
}
```